# Order status and confirmation email problem

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, ce-1.9.0.1, paypal, order-status

Recently I found out that my customers did not receive the automatic confirmation email from my store after they place the order and made payment through Paypal. I need to manually send the confirmation email to customer by clicking the button "send email" in sales>order>order view. The order status also keep remaining in "pending" even though the customer has completed their payment in Paypal.

I would like to know how this can be fixed and also if it is a setting problem or coding problem. I am using Magento ver. 1.9.0.1 now.

Comment: Are you using 1.9.0.1 or 1.9.1.0?

Comment: Did you enable IPN?

Comment: Yes I did. PayPal shows that the IPN was received and confirmed by Magento but the order status does not change and neither does the IPN response show within the order comments. We are using PayPal Payment Standard without SSL and on Sale mode. Also when manually invoicing an order the status does not change and can not be manually changed.

Comment: @sc364 were you able to solve this problem? If so, how?